# How to remove grey borders around individual entries in ggplot2 legend when using theme_bw?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following code in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
p
```

Resulting in this:

[image: ggplot2 grey border in legend]

Each legend entry has a grey border around it. How to remove it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add

```
+ theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA))
```

[image]